# SQL empty result from Query

Tags: database, postgresql

THe problem that I'm struggling with is when the following query has putted in that the result still be empty:

```
SELECT teacher.name, teacher.surname, assignment.code
FROM teacher
JOIN assignment
ON assignment.code = teacher.bsnt
WHERE assignment.working_on_assignment = FALSE
```

What did I wrong?

Comment: what is your data?

Answer (score 0):

If no teachers have any matching assignment records then an empty result set would be expected with an inner join.  You can try doing a left (outer) join, and move the `WHERE` condition to the `ON` clause.

```
SELECT
    teacher.name,
    teacher.surname,
    COALESCE(assignment.code, 'NA') AS code
FROM teacher
LEFT JOIN assignment
    ON assignment.code = teacher.bsnt AND
       assignment.working_on_assignment = FALSE
```

If every teacher has an `NA` code then you will know that there are no matches.

Comment: +one for left join suggestion

Comment: @necromancer I agree with you that the OP should show data but I'm pretty certain nothing is wrong with the data, just with how the query is being phrased.

Comment: yes, it's cool how you worked with incomplete information to generate a good answer!